# Replacing garbage disposal w/ straight pipe. What to do with the wire?

Tags: wiring, plumbing, drain, sink

I'm removing a busted garbage disposal from under the sink and replacing it with straight pipe. I think I can manage this part of the job, but I don't know what to do with the wire. I mean the wire that was hardwired to the garbage disposal. It comes out of a hole in the back of the under-sink cabinet.

Thanks for any help,
Derek

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My guess is you should add a retrofit junction box to terminate the wire; let's see what one of our pros say. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Is it literally a hole? Or is it a Junction box?

Answer (score 1):

### Just terminate it in a junction box with a blank cover

Simply attach a junction box (a "handy box" with the appropriate cable clamp will do) to a nearby piece of cabinet frame, then terminate the cable into the box via the cableclamp, land the bare wire on the ground screw in the box, and terminate the remaining wires individually with wirenuts.  Finish this off with a blank box cover, turn the circuit back on, and you're done!

Comment: And if you want to be really nice to the next owner (or to yourself if you decide you want a garbage disposal or a dishwasher or an instant-hot on the circuit), label the blank plate with the current circuit breaker #.